# how to check sctp port in windows command line?

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, port-scanning, sctp

I want to keep monitor a software using sctp port29169 on my windows machine. However, I tried "netstat -an" and it only shows me the TCP and UDP ports. Is there any way that I can check the sctp port 29169 status in command line in windows locally?(I want to check how many ESTABLISHED connection has been open with this port)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not support SCTP natively in its operating systems, but there is a SctpDrv Windows library for SCTP connections.

There is also a SCTP userspace/userland library (sctplib) that can run on multiple operating systems.

Wireshark also can decode SCTP packets.

Please read further and see if anything is available using these that can be leveraged for your monitoring requirements.

[sctplib](http://www.sctp.de/sctp-download.html)

[SctpDrv](http://www.bluestop.org/SctpDrv/)

Comment: Hi bentek, I alreaday installed SctpDrv to get my sctp working on that windows machine. But do you know if there is any other package or software that allow users to check sctp port in command line?

Comment: I don't know of any offhand, but you can probably utilize Wireshark/TShark command-line options to set up something custom. 
 https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/